# Python TCP server receives only one message out of multiple messages

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have simple code that asks multiple inputs from user and sends it to the server but the server only recieves the first message. How can I make the server get rest of the messages?

Client:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',8000))
for i in range(1,3):
    message = input("Enter your message:")
    s.send(message.encode())
s.close()
```

Server:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 8000))
s.listen(1)
print('ready')
while True:
    c,addr = s.accept()
    sentence = c.recv(1024)
    print(sentence.decode())

c.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the server.py line 7. It awaits to accept connection therefore does not wait to receive data.

For `server.py`

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 8000))
s.listen(1)
print('ready')
c,addr = s.accept()
while True:
    sentence = c.recv(1024)
    if sentence:
        print(sentence.decode())

c.close()
```

For the `client.py`

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',8000))
for i in range(1,3):
    message = input("Enter your message:")
    s.send(message.encode())
s.close()
```